# How can I populate an array during an async call and send it in a response object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

This is an example of what I am trying to do, retrieve all the post inside a mongo db, for each of the post populate the author then use author object to retrieve the profile picture from Cloudinary.

What is the correct way to go about doing this? I've tried numerous ways of populating arrays and sending those in the response but because of the async call they are never run before the res is sent.

```
router.get('/posts',auth, function(req, res, next) {
  //var id = req.payload._id;
  Post.find(function(err, posts){
    if(err){ return next(err); }
    posts.forEach(function(post){
      post.populate('author',function(err,post){
        post.image = cloudinary.image("v"+post.author.avatarVersion+"/profile/"+post.author._id,{
          width:100, height:100,crop:'thumb',gravity:'face',radius:'max'
        })
        //here the post object is updated
        console.log(post)
      })
    })
    //res.json(some posts array);
  });
});
```

Solution thanks to Dan Moldovan!

```
router.get('/posts',auth, function(req, res, next) {
  var id = req.payload._id;

  Post.find({}).populate('author').exec(function(err,posts){
    if(err){ return next(err); }
    var updatedPosts = [];
    posts.forEach(function(post){
      post.image = cloudinary.image("v"+post.author.avatarVersion+"/profile/"+post.author._id,{
          width:100, height:100,crop:'thumb',gravity:'face',radius:'max'
      })
      updatedPosts.push(post);
    })
    res.json(updatedPosts);
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just chain the `populate` query to the first one and have a final callback afterwards such as

```
Post.find({}).populate('author').exec(function (err, posts) {
    if(err){ return next(err); }
    posts.forEach(function(post){
         // here each post will already have author appended
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey Dan, thanks for the reply! That works to make populating more efficient. However I still cannot put the updated posts array in the res.json() .

Comment: forEach is sychronous so you should be able to res.json the array successfuly immediately after the forEach

Answer (score 1):

Dan's solution is correct, but I want to explain the problem you're encountering. Because `post.populate()` is a database call, it means the code is asynchronous. This means the next post in the `forEach()` will start running before the `.populate()` is finished with the previous post. This means that not all posts will be finished before `res.json()` executes. A solution (which is not needed in this case, but can be used by your current code) is to use the [async library](https://github.com/caolan/async):

```
var async = require("async");

router.get('/posts',auth, function(req, res, next) {
    var id = req.payload._id;

    Post.find(function (err, posts) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        // This is a forEach that waits until all posts are populated before moving on
        async.each(posts, function (currentPost, postCallback) {

            currentPost.populate("author", function (err, post) {

                if (err) {
                    return postCallback(err);
                }
                post.image = cloudinary.image("v" + post.author.avatarVersion + "/profile/" + post.author._id, {
                    width: 100, height: 100, crop: 'thumb', gravity: 'face', radius: 'max'
                });
                // the callback function for the current post
                postCallback(); 
            });
        }, function (error) {
            // the final callback function once all postCallback()'s have been executed, or an error

            if (error) {
                return next(error);
            }
            // here, everything is finished
            res.json(posts);
        });
    });
});
```

Again, Dan's solution is correct so don't use this code. Just keep it in mind when you encounter issues like this.

Comment: Thanks! I'm certain this will come in handy.